# Java - Assign specific number of result to an string

Tags: java, arrays, string

Here I have full result in my string

```
formatedString = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.....N}
```

I want to first assign 5 result to lets say

```
formatedString1 = {1,2,3,4,5}
```

then on next call, next five until all the result ends.

```
formatedString1 = {6,7,8,9,10}
```

Is there any way I can do that.

Thanks.

Comment: loops, substring, and many other ways...Also it's helpful when you show what you have tried already.

Comment: please any example sir ?

Comment: I do not see strings here ...

Comment: Are you saying formatedString = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.....N}
 this is a string?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Stream` `offset` and `limit` methods:

```
String str = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
int offset = 0; int limit = 5;
Stream.of(str.split(",")).skip(offset).
            limit(limit).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Just increment offset by  5 each time.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a helper-method like this on a String-Array that you can obtain from your "formatedString":

```
String formatedString = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
String[] arr = formatedString.split(","); // => ["1","2","3",...]

private void call( String[] inputArr, int from, int count )
{
    // check bounds here!
    // "from" must be >0 and < inputArr.length
    // "from" + "count" must be <= inputArr.length

    for( int i = from; i < from+count; i++ )
    {
        // just for safety:
        if ( i>=inputArr.length ) break;

        handle( inputArr[i] );
    }
}
```

call it in a loop like:

```
int step = 5;
for ( int index = 0; index < arr.length; index += step )
{
    // check that index + step do not exceed array length here
    call( arr, index, step );
}
```

For a Java 8 - Stream solution see @Anton's answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to get n numbers each iteration. I would do:

```
public String getN(String st, int n){

    ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i<(st.length/n),i++)
     String aux[n]= new String[n];
     for(int j = 0; j<n;j++){
      aux[j]=st[(i*n)+j]
     }
    res.add(aux(i));
    }

       return res.toString();
   }
```

Can't try it now, but i think it should work.